# How do I join my horizontal slat fence with my neighbor's fence (vertical fence)

Tags: fence

I am thinking about building a horizontal fence to close the open space left by the previous owner to the left of my garage.
How do I join my fence with the exiting fence of my neighbor. Do I have to build my own post next to the one behind the blue garbage bin?

Edit: I am not worried about the legal implications and it does not matter on whose property is the fence. I am just looking for a technical solution

[image]
The picture below shows the intended functionality 
[image]

Update: I looked at that post and it was set in concrete and it is rotten as it is the on to the left side on my neighbor's property. There is another one rotten just behind the small tree at the end of the area that I am trying to cover There is no way that I am going to attach my gate to that post unless I decide to replace it and to split the costs with my neighbor. However doing that will complicate the solution. I am planning on using one of these:
[image]
for the removable central post. I would like to use the same for all the posts but I am not sure if this is advisable. This will be a horizontal fence, made of cedar boards cut of 1x(2" or 3" or 4" or 6")x 8" to match my needs and to build [the design that I am planning to use](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71525/what-type-of-hardware-was-used-for-these-fence-gates)

Comment: I think you meant "slat".

Answer (score 2):

Before you start, talk to your neighbor first, get a feel for any concerns if any they have. Then inspect the post to see if it would hold a section of fence. Then go to it.

EDIT: Ok lets try a different approach, dose your property line split the post, (red line), or meets it (green line)?

[image]

This will make a difference. I would also consider placing a stationary panel first because the swing of you gate would be hitting the curb on the driveway.

Comment: I don't think that my neighbor has a say in how I build my fence. Looks like I will need my own solid post to support the huge gate

Comment: Put a gate wheel on the big gate to reduce racking and outrageous stresses on whatever fence post you use.

Comment: @user2059078 If you're using your own post and are sure of the property line, then you don't need to talk to your neighbor. However, if you're attaching to their fence post (as you imply you're planning on doing in your question), then yes, you absolutely need to talk to them.

Comment: I looked at that post and it was set in concrete and it is rotten as it is the on to the left side on my neighbor's property. There is another one rotten just behind the small tree at the end of the area that I am trying to cover

Answer (score 0):

That pound in metal "fix-it" post anchor, with only about five or six inches of wood post clamp at its top will not be adequate for holding any post upon which you mean to hang a gate. Those metal gadgets can work for repairing any posts that are rotted off inline with some existing fence line but they are not suitable for much else.

Comment: Oh yeah ....the gate hangs on the wall and the post has been standing just fine since I posted hete