# What type of hardware was used for these fence gates?

Tags: hardware

I would like to build a gate like the ones below. What hardware do I have to buy for this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one is a small pipe inside a large pipe, perhaps with some actual bearings, perhaps not.

Second one is just hinges mounted at the corner of the wooden post.

Comment: Thanks Ecnerwal. Any idea what can be used to prevent sagging? I think that his is critical for horizontal fences

Comment: Very long, deeply buried, well-compacted around post. And, since both gate designs you have shown overhang the post, counterweights in the short side of the gate so it's balanced at the post.

Comment: Thanks again. Now when I go for shopping what do I ask for when I want to buy the pair of pipes you mentioned above? Can I but such thing?